# Complex circular symmetric Gaussian and real Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution

Circular symmetric complex Gaussian zero mean PDF is defined as :

$$f(z)= \frac{1}{\pi^N\Vert{M}\Vert} e^{-z^*M^{-1}z}    $$
where $M$ is hermitian semi positive definite, $z \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is determinant operation.

**Question**

If we consider the case of one dimensional vector $z$ containing one real number (i.e., $z=z+0i$), then it should be defined by above relation, but instead it turns out to be $\frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{\sigma ^2}}}{\pi  \sigma ^2}$, from above definition.

The confusion is why it is not $\frac{e^{-\frac{z^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma }$? What am I missing to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Recall that you have a random **complex** $n$-vector $Z$ and the corresponding **real** random $2n$-vector $V$, the dimensions are different. On the one hand you have the **real density** probability:
$$
f_V(v)= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^N\sqrt{||K_V||}} e^{\Large-\frac{v^TK_V^{-1}v}{2}} 
$$ on the other hand you have the **complex density** probability:
$$
f_Z(z)= \frac{1}{\pi^N||K_Z||} e^{-z^*K_Z^{-1}z}.
$$ The relation between these densities is explained [here](http://www.rle.mit.edu/rgallager/documents/CircSymGauss.pdf) (please read section $3$ and section $4$, especially $(10)$-$(13)$).

Comment: So you mean $f_Z(z) \not\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @kaka It is a complex density, yes.

Comment: Is $ e^{-z^*K_Z^{-1}z}$ not a quadratic form, which will always stay positive real for hermitian positive definite $K_Z^{-1}$ ? And so is the determinant of it. And therefore, $f_Z(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @kaka Sorry, I meant a complex distribution. What is the difference between a real normal distribution and a complex normal distribution? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution)